# Split array based on given indices

Tags: matlab, matrix-indexing

I want to split one array into two based on given indices. Specifically, have two arrays, one array A with data (3 columns) and one B with indices.

```
A = [10 11 12; 
     20 21 22; 
     30 31 32; 
     40 41 42]
B = [1 3]
```

As a result, I want two new arrays C and D where C includes all values in A on given indices in B and D including the rest.

```
C = [10 11 12; 
     30 31 32] 
D = [20 21 22; 
     40 41 42]
```

For now, I'm having a loop (check for i in B with ismember and append value in A to array C/D accordingly) but since I have a lot of data, it takes quite long. Any help is appreciated, I know that there is a arrayfunction for everything in matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
A = [10 11 12; 
     20 21 22; 
     30 31 32; 
     40 41 42];
B = [1 3];
```

We can create C with some simple indexing

```
C = A( B, : ); % rows from A indexed by B, all columns
```

And create D using the `setdiff` of all row indices of `A` and the array `B`

```
D = A( setdiff( 1:size(A,1), B ), : ); % rows from A *not* indexed by B, all columns
```

Answer (score 3):

The most challenging part of this question is obtaining `D`. You can assign `A` to `D` without any cost and remove unneeded rows.

```
C = A(B,:);
D = A;
D(B,:) = [];
```

Comment: This solution is especially good if you don't need to preserve `A`, because you can obviously skip the intermediate creation of `D` with `A(B,:)=[]`.